# What's the best way to indicate that text is clickable?

Tags: click

Specifically, the next and previous buttons at the bottom.  I don't want to display it like a hyperlink (i.e. underlined and blue).  Currently, it displays boxes around the two words on hover.  However, I'd rather that it be obvious without having the user scroll over the text.

[image]

Comment: A button, I mean a visible button  (wih border and background-color) ? Isn't that the whole purpose of them ?

Comment: I tried with a button but I couldn't figure out how to make it complement the rest of my webpage

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mark the text as if those were the *reverse* and *fast forward* buttons:

`<< Previous     Page 1 of 1     Next >>`

Also you might want to add some on-hover action (text colour change or background emboss)

Comment: To add to this, another good way to convey clickable is just make them blue (regardless of hover), without the arrows. Blue has become pretty common on the web as "clickable."

Answer (score 2):

Commonly, text that is clickable is underlined and colored [differently](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/106869/whats-the-best-way-to-indicate-that-text-is-clickable). Stylistically, just keeping all clickable text styled the same will lead to the user being able to better *predict* what text will also be clickable later down the road.